# How to show several plots which are saved as an image

Tags: matlab

If i have saved several plots as an image using saveas command how can i show them. The piece of code which i am using is:

```
if we==1
    figure()
    saveas(gcf(),'myownfile.jpg'); % save the figure if condition is satisfied  
    clf % clear the figure after saving it
end
```

The programme checks the condition if we==1 then after saving the plot it clears the figure. Its a part of a function. while the plots which are saved as an image in function have to be shown in the main function. The code is:

```
p=imread('myownfile.jpg');% read the image
imshow(p); %show the image
```

But i am getting a blank figure. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thank you for the help. By removing the command `figure()` and adding the command `saveas(gcf(),strcat('myownpic',strcat(int2str(m1),'.jpg')));` in the above code will solve the problem.

Comment: if this is the solution then you should mark it as the answer to help people out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `()` you have in your code after `gcf` could cause some problems.

Fixed code:

```
if we==1
    figure()
    saveas(gcf,'myownfile.jpg'); % save the figure if condition is satisfied  
    clf % clear the figure after saving it
end
```

Comment: The problem is still there.I want to read all the plots which are saved as an image.But Matlab save them only in one image and when i read that image i get a blank figure.You can just think that all the plots are frames of a video and i have to read them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the `print` command instead since it gives you more control.

```
print(gcf, '-djpeg', '-r400', 'myownfile.jpg')
```

If I had to guess about the problem you have I would bet that you need to call it as: `saveas(gcf,'myownfile.jpg','jpg');`
As Matlab can be very stupid in this.

Another possible problem is the renderer ( use `get/set(gcf,'Renderer')` ) - some of them can not be saved.

Comment: I think i haven't explained my problem explicitly. I have generated 16 plots/figures. When one figure is completed the programme after saving it clears the figure and the process goes on until and unless i get 16 figures in the same manner. According to me; the problem is that, that the programme is not saving the figures as 'myownfile.jpg' as i am getting only one file as 'myownfile.jpg' instead of getting 16 files in my directory.plz help me. i need urgent help.

Comment: also when i read that single file i am getting a blank image.

Comment: can you post a more detailed version of your program?

Comment: ok - for one please add the function to the original question for easier readability.

Comment: in the function roadshape you save BEFORE you plot the graph.

Comment: also you always use the same filename. You need to change it for every different plot.

Comment: Ok-Thanx for the help. Can you kindly tell me that if i want to save the plots with the same file name as 'myownfile(j).jpg' i.e. i only increment the variable 'j' after every plot. would that be possible? i am doing this because after saving the plots as an image i have to read them one by one and then apply some transformations to it. so each time i can't call them with a different file name.Actually by following this procedure i am getting a file named as 'myownfile(j).jpg' in my directory; which is again a blank file.

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you for the help. By removing the command figure() and adding the command saveas(gcf(),strcat('myownpic',strcat(int2str(m1),'.jpg'))); in the above code will solve the problem.